Why am I small? Why aren't I tall?
There's no distinct proper opposite here. We certainly wouldn't use 'Why are I not tall', but 'Why amn't I small' doesn't exist. There must be reasons.
There are a couple of similar questions, not dupes, I believe, and both have answers with dvs. Perhaps someone will come up with a better answer than those?

"Why am I not tall?" I suppose people started saying aren't I because it's easier to say than amn't I.

@KateBunting - maybe, but it's hardly a reason. They do say 'why am I not tall'. I do frequently!

@ermanen - ain't is slang, wouldn't use it in front of King Charles! Aren't is quite acceptable, but why??? Didn't spot that question, with better answers. Should I delete?
